# Retrieve a custom view and its content

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to retrieve a custom contacts view. I'm new to MS Dynamics development but was able to connect to the server and retrieve some basic info and found some examples of building the query/view in code using fetch xml but not to retrieve a custom view. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will, if your custom view has a unique name (within the CRM Org), get the View and execute its FetchXml returning an `EntityCollection`. It should get you started with the basics which you can build out based on your more specific requirements.

*This is starter/learning code only - not intended for deployment without error handling.*

```
    public EntityCollection RetrieveCustomView(string viewName, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var query = new QueryExpression()
        {
            EntityName = "savedview",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fetchxml"),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression()
            {
                Conditions = { new ConditionExpression("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, viewName) }
            }
        };

        var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        if (result.Entities.Any())
        {
            var fetchXml = result.Entities[0].Attributes["fetchxml"].ToString();

            var fetchQuery = new FetchExpression(fetchXml);

            return service.RetrieveMultiple(fetchQuery);

        }

        return null;
    }
```